# Get last argument of last command on ESC-. ZSH Vim mode

Tags: bash, vim, zsh, shortcut

I want to have the same function of Bash+emacs_mode on Zsh+vi_mode, when you type ESC+. you get the last argument of the last command under the cursor. How can I get it on ZSH?

Comment: Doesn't ESC . work in `zsh` also?

Comment: Not on vim mode on my Archlinux box at least.

Comment: ESC . doesn't work as you describe in vim mode in bash, either; it puts you in command mode, then (as far as I can tell) copies the *first* argument of the previous command.

Comment: You are right, is the emacs mode how does what I'm looking for. But the rest still applies.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the same widget (`insert-last-word`) in both `viins` and `emacs` mode; it just isn't bound to a key by default in `viins` mode.

Run the following in the current shell (and add it to `.zshrc` for it to take effect in future shells).

```
bindkey -M viins '\e.' insert-last-word
```